# If I got a correct answer for an identify-this-game question, should I fix the question?

Tags: discussion, editing, game-identification

Maybe this had already been asked, but I did look first so hopefully not.

Due to the nature of game identifying questions, it is not uncommon for the person who asked the question to get some of the details wrong.

Once an answer is received, however, there is a chance to fix the question in order to lose the inaccuracies. This would make it easier for people who remember the game better to stumble across the question in the future. However, this might make some of the other answers seem completely nonsensical as they were based on details (albeit wrong details) that were originally there.

What would be better, then, to leave the question as is or to fix it based on the correct answer?

This is assuming, of course, that the answer itself doesn't point out any discrepancies with the question itself.

Comment: I'd say just **leave it alone**

Answer (score 2):

I think so, yes. Otherwise Google will "associate" wrong information with the game.

Remember that the original question is always kept in the revision history!